# Sorting of iterator after removing elements in loop

Tags: java, loops, iterator, remove-if

In my code I have written a function to get all entries for one specific store.
My query gives all entries back and after iterating in these entries, I remove the query's with the importing parameter Status.

The entries are sorted in a corrected form. After removing the first element, the iterator starts from the bottom and the sorting start from ZtoA instead of from AtoZ.

```
Collection col; 
col = recallStoreHome.findByStoreId(storeid);

for (Iterator it = col.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                RecallStoreEntityLocal recallStore =(RecallStoreEntityLocal) it.next();
                Recall recall = this.getRecall(recallStore.getRecallid());
                if(!recallStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(recall.getStatus()))
                {
                    it.remove();
                }
}


Iterator before: [a, b, c, d, e, f]
Iterator after : [a, f, e, d, c, b]
```

Is it possible to keep the sorting?

result should be:  [a, b, c, d, e, f]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is it possible that the sorting of the iterator stays the same after removing one element? After removing one, the iterator starts iterating from below instead of from above

Comment: What is the datatype of `col`?

Comment: if your recallStoreHome.findByStoreId(storeid); call return a ArrayList it does not prevent order of elements